# find numeric Approximation with Linq when comparing single item to many items in a Collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is there a way to determine the most accurate proximity between single object compare to multiple objects in `IEnumerable Collection` based on their shared `Double` property using `Linq\Lambda`?

I would like to achieve the same result of that function using **Linq**:

```
private ContenderLeague GetWeightApproximationMatch(List<ContenderLeague> group,ContenderLeague contender)
{
    var cont = group[0];

    for (int i = 1; i< group.Count; i++)
    {
        double a = cont.Contender.Weight - contender.Contender.Weight;
        double b = group[i].Contender.Weight - contender.Contender.Weight;

        if (Math.Abs(b) < Math.Abs(a))
        {
            cont = group[i];
        }
    }

    return cont;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `foreach` instead of `for` or use `List<T>.ForEach` (note that its not part of Linq library), but if you insist on using linq:

```
private ContenderLeague GetWeightApproximationMatch(IEnumerable<ContenderLeague> group, ContenderLeague contender)
{
    return group.Aggregate(group[0] ,(selected, checking) =>
    {
        double a = selected.Contender.Weight - contender.Contender.Weight;
        double b = checking.Contender.Weight - contender.Contender.Weight;

        return Math.Abs(b) < Math.Abs(a) ? checking : selected;
    });
}
```